# Linear Homogenous Differential Equation with a discontinuous coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

I am given a differential equation

$$
y'' + (sgn(x))y = 0
$$

Solved piecewise, I get 
$$
y_1 =
\begin{cases} 
\ A Cos(x), x \ge 0\\
\ B e^{-x} , x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
$$
y_2 = 
\begin{cases}
C Sin(x), x \ge 0\\
D e^{x}, x < 0 
\end{cases}
$$
However, ${y_2}$ is not continuous at zero, and in addition to this, the problem gives me a [graphical depiction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CxWB.png) of $y_1$ and $y_2$ and it appears to be that 
$$
y_2 = 
\begin{cases}
C Sin(x), x \ge 0\\
D xe^{-x}, x< 0
\end{cases}
$$
Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there are some ICs given that make the solution work? I found a set of those that give the two curves shown in the graphic.

Comment: The initial conditions given are `y_1(0) = y_2'(0) = 1, y_2(0) = y_1'(0) = 0`

Comment: using those conditions I find that D = 0.

Comment: I realized that was wrong almost immediately after hitting add comment, my apologies. I would love it if you wrote up, I think that I'm quite confused by this problem, or at the very least I'm having trouble seeing where I'm screwing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem makes use of the sign function, which is defined as:

$$sgn(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
~~~1 & \mbox{if}~ x \gt 0\\
-1 & \mbox{if}~ x \lt 0\\
~~~0 & \mbox{if}~ x = 0
\end{array}
\right.$$

We are given a DEQ and initial conditions and asked to find two linearly independent soltuions, such that, $a)$ each satisfies the equation at every point $x \ne 0$ and, $b)$, each has a continuous derivative at $x = 0$. The DEQ and ICS are:

$$y'' + sgn(x) y = 0, \\ y_1(0) = y_2'(0) = 1, y_2(0) = y_1'(0) = 0$$

You have the correct approach by breaking it up into two cases.

If $x \ge 0, y'' + y = 0$ has general solution:

$$y(x) = a \cos x + b \sin x$$

If $x \lt 0, y'' - y = 0$ has general solution:

$$y(x) = c e^{x} + d e^{-x}$$

We can generally write:

$$y(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
a \cos x + b \sin x & \mbox{if}~ x \ge 0\\
c e^{x} + d e^{-x} & \mbox{if}~ x \lt 0
\end{array}
\right.$$

The derivative of this is:

$$y'(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
-a \sin x + b \cos x & \mbox{if}~ x \ge 0\\
c e^{x} - d e^{-x} & \mbox{if}~ x \lt 0
\end{array}
\right.$$

Now, as you have discovered, care has to be taken to properly glue these solutions together to meet the ICs and to be continuous for both $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$.

For $y_1(x), y_1(0) = 1, y_1'(0) = 0$, we have:

$$y_1(0) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
a  & \mbox{if}~ x \ge 0\\
c  + d  & \mbox{if}~ x \lt 0
\end{array}
\right. = 1 \implies a = 1, c + d = 1$$

$$y_1'(0) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
 b  & \mbox{if}~ x \ge 0\\
c  - d  & \mbox{if}~ x \lt 0
\end{array}
\right. = 0 \implies b = 0, c-d = 0 \implies c = d$$

Subbing in $c = d$ into the first, gives $c = d = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

This gives us:

$$y_1(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
 \cos x  & \mbox{if}~ x \ge 0\\
\dfrac{1}{2} (e^{x}+ e^{-x}) & \mbox{if}~ x \lt 0
\end{array}
\right.$$

Repeat this process for $y_2(x)$ and see if you can get it to work.

The plots for $y_1(x)$, blue, and $y_2(x)$, orange are:

[image]

Notice that we have met linear independence and both conditions, $a)$ and $b)$, as required.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is one of those explanations that makes everything click(Although you did accidentally set some of the equations in the piecewise functions to the wrong x-intervals.

Comment: Glad I could help, please report back if you have issues with $y_2(x)$.

Comment: The issue I was having with it, was that I couldn't quite understand how to separate $y_1$ and $y_2$ out from $y$

Comment: Recall, we are asked to find two linearly independent solutions, $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$. All of the information to find those has been provided.